# Turning columns into lists from csv with Python

Tags: python, list, csv, python-3.x, pearson

So I am generally new to Python, and I've been reading many articles but I am still not sure how to ignore the lines with '#' .

I need to:

1. Make the four columns(col2-col5) in this tsv file into separate lists. 
   (How would I chose to ignore the line with Hawaii, since it has incomplete data, therefore using 49 data points. )
2. Then define a function Pearson(X,Y) that takes two lists as parameters and returns the Pearson correlation coefficient. Let X= [x1,x2,...,xn] and Y = [y1, y2,....,yn]. The Pearson Correlation Coefficient between X and Y is given by:

r=(nΣxiyi -ΣxiΣyi)/((√(nΣxi^2-(Σxi^2)^2(nΣyi^2-(Σyi)^2)

```
listT = [26, 24, 23, 14, 15, 19, 21, 22, 18, 17, 16, 23, 24, 21, 20]

listH = [75, 69, 77, 51, 48, 68, 83, 68, 71, 51, 54, 71, 77, 67, 68]

def Pearson(X,Y):
# Do something
    return

# Should print:  var T and var H: 0.8139
print("var T and var H: %.4f"%(Pearson(listT, listH)))
```

While defining the function, how would I write out the Σ sign?

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Data from the CDC -- http://www.cdc.gov/ -- reports on prevalence of
# smoking, incidence of lung cancer, and deaths attributed to smoking.
# 
# Col1: state
# Col2: cases of lung cancer (per 100,000 inhabitants)
# Col3: smoking among adults (%)
# Col4: attempts to quit (%)
# Col5: smoking-related deaths (per 100,000 inhabitants)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alabama 107.1   24.9    47.1    321.1
Alaska  89  24.9    54.2    296.2
Arizona 63.4    18.6    49.4    248.9
Arkansas    105 25.7    45.6    334.1
California  64.4    14.8    51.4    261
Colorado    56.9    20.1    42.4    252.7
Connecticut 81.1    18.1    49  253.8/


Delaware    98.8    24.5    48.7    296
District of Columbia    80.2    21  54.2    257.3
Florida 85.5    20.4    44.2    275.5
Georgia 98.3    20.1    54.8    312.3
Hawaii  68.2    NA  NA  185.1
Idaho   62.7    17.5    47.2    254.1
Illinois    92  22.2    49.3    278.4
Indiana 102.8   25  47.5    322.2
Iowa    91.8    20.8    42.9    256.7
Kansas  84.8    19.8    43.7    270.8
Kentucky    132.6   27.6    47.6    378.1
Louisiana   108 23.6    51.8    309.1
Maine   99.3    21  55.3    303.8
Maryland    80.1    19.7    51.1    279.5
Massachusetts   83.3    18.5    52.5    258.6
Michigan    90  23.4    55.6    296.3
Minnesota   65  20.7    43.6    225.3
Mississippi 115.4   24.6    48.9    343.2
Missouri    103.9   24.1    43  325
Montana 73.1    20.4    45.4    292.6
Nebraska    82.8    20.3    46.7    251.9
Nevada  82.7    23.2    41.4    370.4
New Hampshire   80.6    21.8    53.2    294.8
New Jersey  78.8    18.9    49.6    253.1
New Mexico  57.6    20.3    45.6    250.8
New York    76.7    20  51.5    259.6
North Carolina  104.1   23.2    49.2    307
North Dakota    71.5    19.9    43.9    233
Ohio    97.4    25.9    41.3    310.6
Oklahoma    102.6   26.1    45.1    321.7
Oregon  77.6    20  46  277.5
Pennsylvania    89.4    22.7    47.1    269.1
Rhode Island    84.6    21.3    53.1    283
South Carolina  99.4    24.5    49.1    303.3
South Dakota    78.8    20.3    46.4    253.8
Tennessee   111.1   26.1    46.6    333.6
Texas   83.2    20.6    46.4    287.4
Utah    33.1    10.5    53.7    144.9
Vermont 90.2    20  55.4    272.2
Virginia    86.7    20.9    44.8    288.7
Washington  76.2    19.2    51.6    279.1
West Virginia   120 26.9    46.2    361.6
Wisconsin   75  22  47.7    258.2
Wyoming 57.8    21.7    48.5    294.2
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import operator
import math
import sys

cases_lung_cancer = [] #blank list for 1st column

smoking_adults = [] #blank list for 2nd column

attempts_quit = [] #blank list for 3rd column

smoking_deaths = [] #blank list for 4th column

def Pearson(X, Y)

with open('cdc_data.tsv', newline= ' ') as csv_f:

    for row in csv.DictReader(csv_f, delimiter='\t'):
```

Comment: Use pandas. Watch out for my answer :)

Comment: :) that looks very fast and efficient. But sadly I haven't learned pandas yet, maybe the long way...?

Comment: No worries, go grab it and give it a shot. If you are processing CSV files and computing stuff on them, as I do in my day-to-day work, you will find it really useful.

Comment: Smells like homework. Or your job at work. Either way, it seems like you are using Stack Overflow as you own personal Mechanical Turk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make the four columns(col2-col5) in this tsv file into separate lists,
>   and I chose to ignore the line with Hawaii, since it has incomplete
>   data, therefore using 49 data points.

```
col0 = []
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
col4 = []

f = open('cdc_data.tsv', 'r')
contents = f.read()
lines = contents.split('\n')    # split file into seperate lines
for line in lines:
    if (line[0:1] == '#'):   # filter out comments
       continue

    split_line = line.split('\t')   # split line into seperate words seperated by TAB

    if (len(split_line) < 5): # drop any line that isn't 5 columns
       continue

    # assign each column into a separate list
    col0.append(split_line[0])
    col1.append(split_line[1])
    col2.append(split_line[2])
    col3.append(split_line[3])
    col4.append(split_line[4])
```

I'll leave the issue with Hawaii and your #2 problem as an exercise for you to complete.

Comment: So when I try your method on Python, it outputs: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'.....?

Comment: @liya77 - fixed.  Look for the new line at `contents = f.read()` and the line below it.

Comment: why not `f = open('cdc_data.tsv','r'); lines = f.readlines()` ?

Comment: So the output I get is: NameError: name 's' is not defined  for line: "if (s[0:1] == '#'):"

Comment: @AdamSmith - f.readlines will return a list of individual lines, but each string in that list will still have the trailing '\n'.  You'd have to call `line=line.strip()` on each element in the list before the `line.split('\t')` call.

Comment: @liya77 - fixed.  It should have been "line" not "s"

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_tsv('cdc_data.tsv', header=None)

correlation = data.corr(method='pearson')
```

Comment: Hah, worth the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

col0 = []
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
col4 = []

f = open('cdc_data.tsv', 'r')

def Pearson(X,Y):
    n=50 
    a=0
    b=0
    c=0 
    d=0
    e=0 
    f=0
    g=0 
    for i in range(n):
        a+=X[i]*Y[i]
        b+=X[i]
        c+=Y[i]
        d+=X[i]**2
        e+=X[i] #remember to square this
        f+=Y[i]**2
        g+=Y[i] #remember to square this

    return (n*a-b*c)/(math.sqrt((n*d-e**2)*(n*f-g**2)))


contents = f.read()

lines = contents.split('\n')    # split file into seperate lines
for line in lines:
    if (line[0:1] == '#'):   # filter out comments
       continue
    if (line[0:1] == 'H'): #filter out Hawaii
        continue

    split_line = line.split('\t')   # split line into seperate words seperated by TAB

    if (len(split_line) < 5): # drop any line that isn't 5 columns
       continue

# assign each column into a separate list
col0.append(split_line[0])
col1.append(float(split_line[1]))
col2.append(float(split_line[2]))
col3.append(float(split_line[3]))
col4.append(float(split_line[4]))


print("Correlation for col1 and col2: %.4f" %(Pearson(col1,col2)))
print("Correlation for col1 and col3: %.4f" %(Pearson(col1,col3)))
print("Correlation for col1 and col4: %.4f" %(Pearson(col1,col4)))
print("Correlation for col2 and col3: %.4f" %(Pearson(col2,col3)))
print("Correlation for col2 and col4: %.4f" %(Pearson(col2,col4)))
print("Correlation for col3 and col4: %.4f" %(Pearson(col3,col4)))
```